# Error: A value of type 'num?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num' because 'num?

Tags: flutter, dart

I found this error while running the dart project

> Error: A value of type 'num?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'num' because 'num?'

```
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  print("Enter your birth-year");
  var n = num.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync() ?? "");
  if(n=="") {
    print("Bad Year");
  }
  var age = DateTime.now().year-n;
  print("  ==> You are $age year old!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation of [`num.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-core/num/tryParse.html), the method has an return type of `num?`. This implies that your variable `n` is also of the type `num?` (Nullable num).

So the error points you to the line, where you want to subtract an nullable number from `DateTime.now().year`, which is not allowed.

You can workaround this limitation by using the `??` (Null coalescing)  operator and checking for null and if your `n` is `null` subtract 0.

```
var age = DateTime.now().year - (n ?? 0) ;
```

Another solution is, just using an `if` checking for null followed by an `else` block, like:

```
if(n == null) {
  print("Bad Year");
}
else {
  var age = DateTime.now(). year - n ;
  print("  ==> You are $age year old!");
}
```

---

Taking up your comment:

> i added ! after n and works fine... that is the same solution?

Adding the [null-assertion operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) (`!`) to the `n` in `DateTime.now().year - n!` is not the same solution, but it is a possible solution. And as you already mentioned it compiles and work.

**But be careful:**
You are telling the compiler that you are sure, that `n` will never be null.

With your current code you will get an runtime error, when the user enters a letter or nothing. Then the parsing of that string fails and your `n` is null. And now you want to subtract `null` from the `DateTime.now().year`, which is again not allowed.

*You can read more about Null-Safety on https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety .*

---

*Side note:*

The following check is not correct:

```
if(n=="") {
    print("Bad Year");
}
```

If an incorrect number was entered, your `n` is `null` and this is not equal to an empty string. To get your if clause work, simply use a null check. I also recommend to add a `return` after the output, otherwise your person gets quite old.

```
if(n == null) {
    print("Bad Year");
    return;
}
```

Comment: i added  !   after   n    and works fine...
that is the same solution?

Comment: @AhmedFarag No, as Martin Said "But be careful: You are telling the compiler that you are sure, that n will never be null."